# Reformat name in cell to First Initial. Last Name in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title of my question suggests, I need to take a list of names in a range and reformat them so that they are the first initial, followed by a period and a space, and the last name. For example:

> John Doe

Would become:

> J. Doe

Here is the VBA function that I have written but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Function PLAYERNAMEREFORMAT(Ref As Range) As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim fullName As String
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim initial As String

    For Each Cell In Ref
        fullName = Cell.Value
        firstName = Split(fullName)(0)
        lastName = Split(fullName)(1)
        initial = Left(firstName, 1)
    Next Cell

    PLAYERNAMEREFORMAT = initial + “.” + lastName

End Function
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show your input and desired output screenshot.

Comment: Why don't you use simple LEFT and RIGHT functions to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your function.
Had you done that, you would have gotten a `Variable not Defined` error with regard to the left and right quote marks `“  ”` around your dot.  Those need to be the regular quotes  `"   "`.

Go to the menu `Tools/Options/Editor` and select to Require Variable Declaration.  This will ensure that any new modules will be created with Option Explicit.

I don't understand why this is not the default.

PS: you'll also need to add your space after the dot. `". "`

Comment: Also remember to put in the space after the period.

Comment: + For suggesting Option Explicit.

Comment: @ImranMalek I **really** don't understand why that is not the default.  It adds so much to ease of debugging.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I believe lot of newbies do this all the time considering that their code is very small and does pretty much what they want it to do but while doing this they are not only letting bugs exist in the code but they are also suppressing its detection.

Comment: I think newbies aren't necessarily targeting for code shortness, but trust (F1) help and its examples 
which don't lead to best practice if they leave aside
*`Option Explicit`* statements, *declarations* and sufficiently *qualified references*. 
So I'd plead as well for a default setting of `Option Explicit` in the VBE and for actually *examplary* examples. +1:)

Comment: @T.M. I agree. But it's been that way since the beginning -- unfortunate that change in this area is glacial.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using UDF for this, try this formula

e.g. If your name is in cell B1 then

> =LEFT(B1,1)&". "&RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH(" ",B1))